# comet example. I don't get it

Tags: asp.net, comet

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Buffer = false;

    while (true)
    {
        Response.Write(Delimiter + DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss.FFF"));
        Response.Flush();

        // Suspend the thread for 1/2 a second
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
    }

    // Yes I know we'll never get here, it's just hard not to include it!
    Response.End();
}
```

When Response.Flush() is executed, the new webpage is sent to the client
The while block will run forever on the server
When the new maeeage reaches the client, there is a refresh for the new data
How is it posible to continue the same place. Shouldn't there be a new Page object created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few problems with what you've described...

1) You've described mis-matching client and server code. The server code there only works with a single AJAX request that hangs around forever, and gets notified on the client but *doesn't start a new request*. In your comments, however, you've described a client that *does start a new request*. Those 2 concepts won't work together.

2) Elaborating on point 1, the request never ending means that most browsers will never see it. "Typical" AJAX requests won't change state until the entire contents arrive, so that request will just hang forever. You'll have to end the request, or use an XHR request that changes state as each chunk is flushed from the server, which only would be viable in certain browsers.

3) Even if 1) worked, proxies, etc, would kill the request eventually. They don't like requests sitting around forever.

4) That's a blocking synchronous request, which'll eat server resources like crazy. That won't get beyond a the threadpool limit before it fails catastrophically.

So yea, the example you've given here doesn't make sense :).